# Rules sending email to profile2 users

Tags: rules, emails, users

I am new to drupal. I have installed profile2 module and created one profile named as "Travel Agency". Now I want to send different mail to this user when he/she registered with my site as "Travel Agency". so I have created a Rule for this and it is working it is sending a separate mail which has been setted for the Profile2 user or Travel Agency users.

**My rule information is as follows:**

Event: After saving a new profile

Condition: Data Comparison .. Selected data: profile2:type equals Travel Agency

Action: send e-mail

The problem is that along with this email it is also sending the email which has been sent to user when he/she registered as Normal user with my site.

Please guide me on this. Thanks for the answers in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go to admin/config/people/accounts and uncheck "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account." Then create a new email rule for users who are not "Travel Agency". If you still need to require e-mail verification before the user logs in then check out the [Mail Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailcontrol) module.